# Test fails: association id should be mandatory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, associations, integration-testing

I have the following integration tests:

```
def setup
  @file = fixture_file_upload('test/fixtures/rails.jpg')
  @user = users(:one)
  @image = @user.build_image(image_file: @file)
end

test "should be valid" do
  assert @image.valid?
end

test "image_file should be present" do
  @image.image_file = "     "
  assert_not @image.valid?
end

test "user_id should be present" do
  @image.user_id = "     "
  assert_not @image.valid?
end
```

The last integration test fails -- i.e., `@image` is valid -- which I don't understand. Given the migration file below, shouldn't `user_id` be mandatory?

```
def change
  create_table :images do |t|
    t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
    t.string :image_file, null: false

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.valid?` only checks your validations from your models and not from your schema. What you need to do is add validations in your image model also

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

plus any other validations that you might want to use.